# gui within a gui - tkinter python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to embed a chat system (that is a gui) within another gui I have already created. I have tested the chat application separately (it uses socket programming) and it works fine, but when I copy and paste that code into the original gui application (so that when I press a button it opens the chat application), it stops working.

I don't know why this is happening, so any insight would be helpful. I have a feeling it has something to do with the fact that I am trying to run a gui within a gui, but I am not sure, as this is the first time I'm working with python gui's.

Comment: Are you using tkinter's `Tk` window to run both? If so that might be your problem. You should never open two `Tk` windows. If that is the case you should change your chat window to a `Toplevel` window instead.

Also you should probably add some code examples of the problem you are experiencing as it is hard to know exactly what your problem is.

Comment: @MatthewG this worked!! thank you so much - I've been stuck for ages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Tkinter Toplevel window instead of Tk window. You should never have two Tk windows.